# Open source (Linux Hostable) e-commerce/storefront projects

Tags: e-commerce, storefront

My company is a Microsoft/C# focused. We are looking to offer e-commerce sites as apart of our services. We have identified a number of .Net opensource/paid-for e-commerce  solutions that we can make use off, the down side of these is windows server costs.

So Im looking for a Linux host-able e-commerce solutions. Can anyone recommend any?

The most important requirement it that, its a good bit of kit. i.e. well written, easily skinnable, modifiable/pluggable. We dont really care what language its written in. I guess Java would be slightly beneficial as its similar to C#, but php, ruby etc are all acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/) (a module for [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) CMS) is very good and modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

[Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) is an open source framework for building online stores with Django.